# Unable to Turn iTunes Match Off

Tags: itunes

I Have some mp3 files in my iTunes library that will not go through iCloud, i.e., the cloud icon has a line through it.  When I disable iTunes Match on the pull down menu, iTunes still has "iTunes Match is on".  Please Help!

Comment: Maybe mention which OS, which iTunes version, which menu ...

Comment: I found the solution to my problem!  I turned iTunes Match off on the phone itself.  Now I am able to sync all my files manually!

Comment: We encourage people to answer their questions in the answer section. That lets other people know how you solved your problem. Could you explain the sequence on how to solve this as a full answer?